# Align table code text with image

Tags: css

I am trying to align some table code so the text does not overlap.

You can see an example here: http://henryless.us.tempcloudsite.com/wp/key-personnel/

I have tried just about every CSS style to align these, any ideas on something to align this?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/O5Ifvrw.gif

Comment: post the code or fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add this

```
tr td p:last-child{margin: 0px 30px;}
```

I am not sure what all that is going to effect, but it seems to align them closer.  Try to use your developer tools in browser (press F12).  You can edit the style of elements so you can figure out what you need to change.